# What's wrong with this async aiohttp code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

For the following code using aiohttp:

```
async def send(self, msg, url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.post(url, data=msg) as response:
            self._msg = response.read()

async def recv(self):
    return await self._msg
```

It works... Most of the time, but occasionally (frequently, actually) results in various exceptions - usually truncated responses, or a connection already being closed exception.

By contrast, the following works perfectly:

```
async def send(self, msg, url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.post(url, data=msg) as response:
            self._msg = await response.read()

async def recv(self):
    return self._msg
```

I would like to know why, as the second version is technically incorrect for my purposes and I need to fix it. (It is incorrect because the recv function might be called before the response has been read)

Comment: "It is incorrect because the recv function might be called before the response has been read" - if it's called before the response has been read, then what's it going to `await` in the first version? `self._msg` hasn't been set yet.

Comment: Exactly, the code I have just happens to never call recv until well after send has completed. But ah, that's a really good point, it turns out that *both* versions are fundamentally wrong.  Can you suggest a fix, while still keeping the 'send' and 'recv' conceptually separate?

Comment: (To clarify: Whilst I'd appreciate the fix, the real answer I want out of this is to understand the difference between those two code samples)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`with` is a context manager, it runs some code before and after any statements within it's block, bookkeeping usually. Meaning, your first `recv` function most likely awaits on a future that references an already closed connection, or something along these lines.

Let's say you have some code that looks like this:

```
with open(...) as file:
    file.read()
```

This is what it does, roughly:

```
file = open(...)
file.read()
file.close()
```

And this is the equivalent of what you're doing in your first example:

```
file = open()
file.close()
...
file.read()
```

Comment: And that invalidates the future?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by "invalidates the future" exactly, but, basically, this whole thing is not an asyncio issue. It's an issue of reading from a closed socket, or something else that happens deep in the `response.read()`.

Comment: Updated the answer.